# Getting error when a project developed in Laravel 5.0 & PHP 5.6 version version, trying to run in PHP 7.2 version

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, php-5.6, php-7.2

When I set up the Laravel 5.0 version project in PHP 7.2 I am getting following error. Please help me how to run this in PHP 7.2 version or is there any other way.

> ErrorException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 16: Use of
>   undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128'
>   (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: in docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.0 => PHP >= 5.4, PHP < 7 So update to laravel 5.6 required PHP >= 7.1.3

Comment: Laravel 5.0 has been end of life for over a year, if you're upgrading PHP, you might as well upgrade your Laravel install too.   5.6 is the latest release, 5.5 is the long term release so it will be supported a bit longer.